# How to get Content Location in Response?

Tags: java, mongodb, post, jersey

I am using a java REST service for storing data in Mongodb using **POST** method in response it will return me an **id** which will be used to retrieve the data back.
I want to get the id in `contentLocation` how can i do so??
Here is my `POST` method for which I need `contentLocation`

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) throws FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
    filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + fileDetail.getFileName();

    // save the file to the server
    Mongodb_storage location =new Mongodb_storage();
    location.store_in_db(uploadedInputStream,
            FilenameUtils.getExtension(filePath));
    String output = "File saved to server location " + filePath;
    return Response.status(200).contentLocation(new URI("/53c5ac66796029898a5197d4")).entity(output).build();//here I have used content location
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just set the content-location in response header like

```
 response.addHeader("Content-Location", your_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP `Content-Location` header is used for an alternate location of the returned data. What you probably need is `Location` header that is used when a new resource has been created.

1. First build URI containing the given ID and used to retrieve the created data back. You can use for example `UriBuilder` class to build such a URI.
2. Then return HTTP 200 OK response with `Content-Location` header containing your URI

   ```
   Response.ok().contentLocation(locationUri)).entity(entity).build();
   ```
3. Or return HTTP 201 Created response with `Location` header containing the URI

   ```
   Response.created(locationUri).build();
   ```

Comment: Add code of your REST service for storing data to the question so that we know what you have already tried.

Comment: It seems to be OK. Do you get any exception or what is wrong?

Comment: It is not generating content location

Comment: Do I get it right that the text "File saved to ..." is returned (as a response body) but Content-Location header is not present? How do you test it?

Comment: Yes you get it right.I am testing response in **Postman client** and to test the contents I moves towards the header tab.

Comment: Can you try another tool (e.g. cURL) to ensure that the problem is with your code and not with your tool?

Comment: No I have not test it on any other tool.